# jquery seems not to work inside bootstrap 4 popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to send data via jquery (jquery-3.2.1.min.js) and ajax from inside of a bootstrap popover.
The popover works fine, but I cannot get the submit to work.

I initialized the popover with

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function(){

        $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
            html : true,
            content: function() {
                var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
                return $(content).children(".popover-body").html();
            },
            title: function() {
                var title = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
                return $(title).children(".popover-heading").html();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

This is the html trigger:

```
<span tabindex="0" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-popover-content="#comment230" data-original-title="" title="">
    <img src="/ds/img/comment.svg" alt="comment" height="16px">
</span>
```

And this is the html inside the popover:

```
<div id="comment225" style="display:none;">
    <div class="popover-heading">Comments</div>
    <div class="popover-body">
        <div class="commentbody">
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="input text">
                        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                        <input name="comment" id="comment" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <button class="submittest" id="acomment225button">Test</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For testing reasons I did this:

```
$(".submittest").click(function(e) {
    alert('test');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The alert does not work from buttons inside the popover, but from buttons placed on the rest of the page. 
How can I get this to work?

Comment: This is because the elements are not part of the DOM at the point where you try to select them. Go read up on the keyword _event delegation_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those DOM elements are not present at the time you are subscribing to the event.

You need to hook up to events in this fashion:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submittest", function(e){
   alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thyan you very much.